# SQL Server Job Expression for Variable Failed Evaluation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that runs without errors locally. It is then deployed to the catalog and run in a SQL Agent job. Functionally, the job runs correctly and all data is where it should be, but it always kicks out this error:

> The expression for variable "TextMaxDate" failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression.

I have not been able to find a more meaningful message. The SSIS package has three variables...

1. TextMaxDate

   - Data type = `DateTime`
   - Expression = `@[User::TextMaxDate]`
2. TextSQL_Content

   - Data type = `String`
   - Expression = `"SELECT CREATED_DATE, ID, TEXT FROM SRC_SCHEMA.SRC_TABLE_1
     WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '" + (DT_STR, 12, 1252)(DT_DBDATE) DATEADD("day",1,(DT_DBDATE)@[User::TextMaxDate])  + "' AND '" + (DT_STR, 25, 1252) (DT_DBDATE) DATEADD( "day", - 1 , (DT_DBDATE) GETDATE() ) + "'"`
3. TextSQL_NoContent

   - Data type = `String`
   - Expression = `"SELECT ID, CREATED, CREATED_BY, TEXT FROM SRC_SCHEMA.SRC_TABLE_1 
     WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '" + (DT_STR, 12, 1252)(DT_DBDATE) DATEADD("day",1,(DT_DBDATE)@[User::TextMaxDate])  +  "' AND '" + (DT_STR, 25, 1252) (DT_DBDATE) DATEADD( "day", - 1 , (DT_DBDATE) GETDATE() ) + "'"`

and follows this flow...

1. Execute SQL Task

   - SQLStatement is set to `select max(cast(created_date as date)) MaxDate from DEST_SCHEMA.table_1`.
   - Result Set sets Result Name to `MaxDate` and Variable Name to `User::TextMaxDate`
2. Data Flow Task (Oracle Attunity Driver)

   - Under Expressions...[Oracle Source].[SqlCommand] set to `@[User::TextSQL_NoContent]`
   - Loads data into DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_1, but doesn't map the `TEXT` column so that it  is null for each inserted record.
3. Data Flow Task (OLE DB Source Editor)

   - Data Access Mode set to `SQL command from variable`
   - Variable Name set to `User::TextSQL_Content`
   - Loads data into DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_2
4. Execute SQL Task

   - SQLStatement set to `UPDATE DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_1 SET DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_1.TEXT b.TEXT from DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_1 a join DEST_SCHEMA.TABLE_2 b  on a.id = b.id where a.TEXT IS NULL`

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: What is the value/expression of `@[User::NoteMaxDate]` variable?

Comment: The value is dynamic at runtime, so when I go into the package, it's the date/time that it first ran (i.e. `6/26/2019 2:02 PM`). `EvaluateAsExpression` is set to `True` because it is being used by the other variables.

Comment: `EvaluateAsExpression` must be set to `True` if it is an expression not **because it is being used by the other variables**

Comment: It is automatically set to `True` when being used by other variables, right? Isn't it necessary to be set to `True` in order to dynamically populate?

Comment: No that's not true. you have to set `EvaluateAsExpression` to `True` only if it is evaluated based on an Expression. `TextMaxDate` must have this property set to `True` but `@[User::NoteMaxDate]` No

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - there was a typo. `TextMaxDate` is set to `@[User::TextMaxDate]`

Comment: So what is the default value of `@[User::NoteMaxDate]`? `EvaluateAsExpression` is set to `True`? How value it is assigned?

Comment: again...sorry for the continued confusion - see my edited comment. `TextMaxDate` is set to `@[User::TextMaxDate]`. Value is assigned in step 1 of the flow.

Comment: Why writing an expression to set `@[User::TextMaxDate]` = `@[User::TextMaxDate]` !! Just remove the expression and set `EvaluateAsExpression` to `False`

Comment: So leave the Expression for `TextMaxDate` blank and switch `EvaluateAsExpression` to `False`?

Comment: Yes and also make sure that `select max(cast(created_date as date)) MaxDate from DEST_SCHEMA.table_1` is returning a value

Comment: that ran with no errors - thank you. however, how can I verify that the `TextMaxDate` with blank expression is actually being passed the correct date at runtime? Is there anything in the execution reports that would tell me this?

Comment: In visual studio you can add a watch on the variable. In SQL Server agent Job i think you have to edit the package and export this value (result of sql task) to a table or external file to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why writing an expression to set `@[User::TextMaxDate]` = `@[User::TextMaxDate]` !!

Just remove the expression and set EvaluateAsExpression to `False`. Also make sure that

```
select max(cast(created_date as date)) MaxDate from DEST_SCHEMA.table_1
```

is returning a value.